# How do I install a second screen?

Tags: display

I bought a second-hand screen yesterday and realised I onbly have one VGA-port but also a DVI-port. I went to the store to see if I can get a cable to have two monitors. He said that wasn't possible with only one port. I think he was wrong.

My monitors both have VGA cables but I think there's a way to use the DVI-port to install one of the screens. For the record, I want two different screens, so a DVI splitter wont work. I think my videocard supports two screens because of this: http://gyazo.com/d0abb01e55ff03e66623308076a872a3 Translation: "Add/remove screen" and "detect screen" Also this: http://windows.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows-vista/add-a-second-monitor EDIT: this is exactly what is on the back of my pc.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an adapter that will take the DVI-I port from your graphics card and turn it into a VGA port, these are usually included with graphics cards, but can be purchased separately for very cheap.

Your setup would end up as 1 monitor in your VGA port and the other in your DVI-I port, assuming you're using windows, you can then just go in and adjust the settings to your liking in display options.

Comment: Mark it as answered if it works :p

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind a VGA port and DVI port is so you can have either of the ports, but not both in use at the same time.

So the salesman is correct to say that it will not work to just convert the output to the right format.

There is however a cable for sale that will split a signal allowing 2 monitors to work on one port if you use DVI.

This is the cable you'd need:
[image]

Comment: This is not always correct, the vast majority of graphics cards do not slave one port to the other if they only have two ports, this is especially true between a digital (DVI) and analog (VGA) port. The majority of slaving is between two digital ports, usually a DVI and HDMI port, or DVI and Display port.

Comment: Yes, which is why I suggested a cable for the DVI port. I've tested this cable with a few different common VGA cards about a year ago, and it all worked, surprisingly also on a few on-board intel chips.

Comment: That cable in the picture is not a generic DVI splitter.  It's a [DMS-59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59) to DVI breakout cable.  You'd need a video adapter with a DMS-59 connector. :)

Comment: I've changed the picture to one that makes it more noticable. Note that there are those with VGA and DVI outputs. This image just had the DMS-59 written in it.

Comment: @LPChip - I can tell by the connector that the black connector isn't a DVI connector.